# Setting Bitmaps from ViewModels in Uno.Platform won't work for Android

Tags: android, .net, uwp, uno-platform

I'm playing with Uno.Platform and my ViewModel has this kind of code:

```
new Item
{
    Name = "Mario",
    Number = 11,
    Image = new Uri("ms-appx:///mario.png", UriKind.Absolute)
},
```

Then, in XAML I have an `<Image Source="{Binding Image}" />`

Problem? it only works for UWP and Web heads

If I want to make it work in Android I have to place the bitmaps inside the **Resources\drawables** as **AndroidResource** and change the Uri to => `new Uri("mario.png")`, but that breaks UWP and Web.

Is there a good way to overcome this limitation?

---

### UPDATE

As @JeromeLaban suggested I updated Uno.UI to the latest version (pre-release) and it started working! I'm using ms-appx:/// absolute uris all the way. Sadly **this broke the Web head Image using Bindings.**

A workaround is to edit the linker file: Into the WASM project, go to the LinkerConfig.xml and add this inside the  node

```
<assembly fullname="System">
    <type fullname="System.*Converter" />
</assembly>
```

Comment: Which version of the Uno.UI package are you using? There were issues in some builds of Uno regarding local assets, try with the latest dev package.

Comment: Thanks! It was set to 1.43.-dev.657. I've updated it and it now works! :D However, I'm having problems with other images not showing. I have an <Image Source= "mario.png" /> that doesn't show in the Web head and it does in Android and UWP.

Comment: @JeromeLaban Is there any document to see how to correctly load images that work properly in all the heads? I'm a bit lost in this topic. It could help a lot. Maybe inside Uno.Platform's Wiki

Comment: @JeromeLaban Spoke too quick, this kind of Uri work for Android and UWP but doesn't show for Web (when used via Binding) ==> new Uri("ms-appx:///mario.png", UriKind.Absolute)

Comment: @SuperJMN Can you write an answer to your question and accept it? So that the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JeromeLaban suggested I updated Uno.UI to the latest version (pre-release) and it started working! I'm using ms-appx:/// absolute uris all the way. Sadly this broke the Web head Image using Bindings. 
A workaround is to edit the linker file: Into the WASM project, go to the LinkerConfig.xml and add this inside the node

```
<assembly fullname="System">
    <type fullname="System.*Converter" />
</assembly>
```